# Jenkins ignores multiple build triggering for the same job

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, automation, continuous-integration

I'm trying to trigger a job on my Jenkins for multiple times at the same time. But it looks like Jenkins is ignoring all builds I triggered when the very first build starts to run.

For example, in the screenshot below, I clicked the `builds start` button for 5 times with no delay. It is showing 5 builds on the queue as I expected.

[image: Jenkins build waiting list]

But once the job gets started after the executor (Kubernetes) becomes ready, the build queue suddenly gets cleaned up. Seems like the very first job I've triggered is only being executed, and the other queued jobs are just... gone.

[image]

[image]

I need to queue all jobs correctly for my use case. Is this a bug? Or is there something that I'm missing? How do I find a walkaround?

I'm running the latest `stable/jenkins` Helm chart on my Kubernetes v1.16.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your number of executors value?

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins, you've to set `# of executors` value to a higher number if you need to run multiple parallel jobs. By default, it's zero.

[image]

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately, I don't see that option at my Jenkins - Settings - Nodes. 

I am using the Kubernetes Plugin to make my Kubernetes cluster as an executor.

Something similar I can find is "Concurrency Limit" at "Configure Cloud" - "Kubernetes" menu. It is set as 10 right now.

Comment: You can find it at `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I was able to find that option and now increased it to 10. Triggering multiple builds without delay works well with the manual build trigger button at Jenkins. But I'm still having the issue when I use the "Generic webhook trigger" plugin to trigger. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?